# Liquibase MySQL alter table's character set

Tags: mysql, utf-8, liquibase

Is there a more appropriate Liquibase XML way of altering a table's character set?
Right now I'm using

```
<changeSet>
    <sql>alter table <table_name> convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Is there something like

```
<modifyTable changeSet=utf8 />
```

Comment: Back up a step, and explain the goal.  What kind of text do you have?  Do you have something failing now?  Do you already have data in the table(s)?  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Liquibase has no specific changeset type for altering a table's character set, so doing it in native SQL is the right way to go. However, since I am not that familiar with MySQL/MariaDB, I cannot predict how MySQL will treat existing data in your table.